# from for loop to apply to speed up in R

Tags: r

I am running a for loop with two matrices.  One `matrix(A)` has ~100 strings (such as, name1, name2, ..., name100) and only has one column.  The other `matrix(B)` is bigger than `A` with rows and columns of both values and strings.  In some places in `B` matrix, each name of `A` matrix is matched.  I would like to extract and stack matched entire rows with a particular string of matrix `A` on output matrix.

So, I am running as below,

```
output <- NULL
for(K in 1:nrow(A)){
  print(K)
  for(cc in 1:nrow(B)){
    for(dd in 1:ncol(B)){
      if(toupper(A[K])==toupper(B[cc,dd])){
        output <- rbind(output,B[cc,])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it is too slow.  How do you make this for loop more efficient in terms of running time?

Comment: Is the B matrix really a `matrix`, or is it a `data.frame`? A `matrix` can only have one type - so all values would be strings then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some idea:

```
A <- matrix(c('a','b','c','d'), ncol=1)
B <- data.frame(z1=c('a','g','f','c'), z2=rnorm(4), z3=c('a','b','f','f'))

id <- apply(B, 2, function(x) A %in% x)
newB <- B[apply(id,1,sum)>0, ]
```

Comment: I get "Error in apply(kk, 1, sum) : object 'kk' not found"?

Answer (score 5):

The speed problem is not because of the for-loop. `apply` will probably be even slower. You need to pre-dimension your target-object and assign values with indexing.

Or you need to think of a vectorized solution like ... works on Manuel's test case:

```
 idx <- unique(which(toupper(as.matrix(B)) %in% toupper(A), arr.ind=TRUE) %% NROW(B))
 idx[idx==0] <- 4
     B[idx , ]
  z1         z2 z3
1  a  1.5623285  a
4  c -1.2196311  f
2  g  0.2551535  b
```

Comment: Your expression is wrong. You must include the A vector, and I think the [,1] in which is also wrong.

Comment: Untested algorithms are often wrong. I'll put in one that works. Care to compete on speed?

Comment: why you assign idx[idx==0]<-4 ?

Comment: @DWin - I compared the speeds. We all get different results though :-)

Comment: @ManuelRamón : Since I used modulo remainders I got "0"'s at the end of a run of 4 so I needed to restore it to the proper number for R's indexing which doesn't start at 0.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fast solution that should give the same output as yours:

```
set.seed(13)
A <- matrix(letters[1:5])
B <- matrix(sample(letters, 12, rep(T)), 4)

x <- match(toupper(A), toupper(B), nomatch=0L)
x <- (x[x>0L]-1L) %% nrow(B) + 1L
output <- B[x, , drop=FALSE]
```

It works by using `match` to find the (vector) indices in B where A matches. It then converts those indices to row indices, and finally extracts those rows.

..Note that the row `B[2,]` is included twice in the output - is that really what you want? If not, change the last line to:

```
output <- B[unique(x), , drop=FALSE]
```

**EDIT** Some timings. I removed the `toupper` calls since that dominates the times, and @Manuel Ramon didn't call it. Note that all our outputs are different! So some debugging is probably warranted ;-)

```
# Create huge A and B matrices
set.seed(13)
strs <- outer(letters, LETTERS, paste)
A <- matrix(strs)
B <- matrix(sample(strs, 1e7, rep(T)), 1e4)

# My solution: 0.24 secs   
system.time({
 x <- match(A, B, nomatch=0L)
 x <- (x[x>0L]-1L) %% nrow(B) + 1L
 output1 <- B[unique(x), , drop=FALSE]
})

# @DWin's solution: 0.91 secs
system.time({
 idx <- unique(which(as.matrix(B) %in% A, arr.ind=TRUE) %% NROW(B))
 idx[idx==0] <- 4
 output2 <- B[idx, , drop=FALSE]
})

# @Manuel Ramon's solution: 0.89 secs
system.time({
  id <- apply(B, 2, function(x) A %in% x)
  output3 <- B[apply(id,1,sum)>0, ]
})
```

Comment: Aw shucks. I was sure mine was faster especially since Ramon's had two apply loops. Thanks, @Tommy. We obviously need a better set of test cases for debugging.